# Windows 10 Desktop shortcut not starting new session

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I have created batch file with specific settings for my work. I have created desktop shortcut to launch batch file and assigned Shortcut to it. But when I press shortcut keys, It only launches one session, unlike other application shortcut(When after pressing shortcut keys new session gets launched.) How can I start new session for every shortcut key press ?

I used target of shortcut as **cmd.exe /k D:\WorkDir\Scripts\launchDevEnv.bat**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following as the command of the shortcut :

```
cmd.exe /c start "" cmd.exe /k D:\WorkDir\Scripts\launchDevEnv.bat
```

This will start a new CMD session, while the `cmd.exe /c` session
terminates immediately after.

(Note that programs residing in `C:\Windows\System32` don't need
a full path.)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !